# dateTime to Epoch and vice versa xslt

Tags: xslt

I have been trying to convert a given dateTime to epoch time and also a given epoch time to dateTime. I am quite new to xslt and have been struggling with this quite for some time, it is not giving me back any results. Here is my xslt so far

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:ns0="http://www.NoPreAuth.org"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl ns0 xsd">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="date1">
        <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:NoAuthInput/ns0:StartDate"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="date2">
        <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:NoAuthInput/ns0:EndDate"/>
</xsl:variable>
<ns0:NoPreAuthInput>
<ns0:Product>
        <xsl:value-of select="/ns0:NoAuthInput/ns0:Product"/>
</ns0:Product>
<!-- datTime to epoch -->
<ns0:END_T> 
  <xsl:value-of select= "(('$date1')  - xsd:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00') )  div  xsd:dayTimeDuration('PT1S') "/>
</ns0:END_T>
<!-- epoch To datTime -->
<ns0:Closed_T> 
  <xsl:value-of select= "(('$date2')  + xsd:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00') )  *  xsd:dayTimeDuration('PT1S') "/>
</ns0:Closed_T>
</ns0:NoPreAuthInput>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the xml which I am trying to convert is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<NoAuthInput xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.NoAuth.org 

 xmlns="http://www.NoAuth.org">
   <Product>ABC</Product>
   <StartDate>2015-10-05T15:52:40.782</StartDate>
   <EndDate>1444150760</EndDate>
</NoAuthInput>
```

any help on this much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9, XmlPrime or AltovaXML to have support for the `dateTime` data type and for durations and computations. Are you using an XSLT 2.0 processor? And the XSLT snippet does not declare the `xsd` prefix so I don't think your code would compile. To convert your input into a `dateTime` use `<xsl:variable name="date1" select="xsd:dateTime(/ns0:NoAuthInput/ns0:StartDate)"/>`, then you can use `$date` for computations.

Comment: Thanks Martin, actually the schema location is some local file to the project directory, and yes I am using xslt 2.0. I did modify the code as suggested, but it says "Error: Arithmetic operator is not defined for arguments of types (xs:double, xs:dateTime)" . Can you please suggest more on this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To convert [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to ISO 8601 date-time:

```
<xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00') + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('PT', UnixTime, 'S'))"/>
```

To convert [ISO 8601 date-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) to Unix time;

```
<xsl:value-of select="floor((xs:dateTime(ISODateTime) - xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00')) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')) "/>
```

Requires XSLT 2.0.

Working demo: http://xsltransform.net/94rmq5L

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this in XSLT 1.0 on MSXML (I know the original asker is not):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:userCSharp="http://stackoverflow.com/xsltexample">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="userCSharp:DateToEpoch('1970-01-02')" />
  </xsl:template>
  <msxsl:script language="CSharp" implements-prefix="userCSharp"><![CDATA[
     public string DateToEpoch(string s)
     {
         DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(s);  
         DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

         return (dt - epoch).TotalSeconds.ToString();
     }
   ]]></msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Replace the `'1970-01-02'` with whatever text node you want and this should work, as long as that node was a valid date time.  If not, it's easy enough to write up another simple method to do that using `DateTime.Parse/TryParse`.  The output of this template (against any valid XML) would be `86400`.  Note that it's best to define methods in a `CDATA` node to avoid needing to escape quotes or angle brackets (this code doesn't happen to use any but might be extended to for some reason).

Comment: Right Dan xslt 2.0 was tha ask, still thanks for the effort !

Comment: Cool example, really needed this :)