# Convert timestamp to date with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, timestamp, xslt-1.0

How can I convert a timestamp in xslt 1.0 without EXSLT extensions or date functions.

```
<timestamp>1569509813</timestamp>
```

I thought this would be trivial, but its not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to ISO 8601 date-time in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:template name="UnixTime-to-dateTime">
    <xsl:param name="unixTime"/>

    <xsl:variable name="JDN" select="floor($unixTime div 86400) + 2440588" />
    <xsl:variable name="secs" select="$unixTime mod 86400" />   

    <xsl:variable name="f" select="$JDN + 1401 + floor((floor((4 * $JDN + 274277) div 146097) * 3) div 4) - 38"/>
    <xsl:variable name="e" select="4*$f + 3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="g" select="floor(($e mod 1461) div 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="5*$g + 2"/>

    <xsl:variable name="d" select="floor(($h mod 153) div 5 ) + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="(floor($h div 153) + 2) mod 12 + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="floor($e div 1461) - 4716 + floor((14 - $m) div 12)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="H" select="floor($secs div 3600)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="M" select="floor($secs mod 3600 div 60)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="S" select="$secs mod 60"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$y"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, '00')"/>
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($d, '00')"/>
    <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($H, '00')"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($M, '00')"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($S, '00')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCRZ/2

---

For XSLT 2.0, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32977307/3016153

Comment: This works in the fiddle.  I use Visual Studio 2017 to test and it didn't work there.  Not your fault...Visual Studio's fault.  VS says 'Format specifier was invalid'....An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Data.SqlXml.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Format specifier was invalid. occurred.

Comment: @TomMcDonald How about this one? xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCRZ/2